# using :onkeyup=> for a f.text_field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a partial with the below code:

```
<%= form_for :subString_typed, :controller => "deployment_group", :remote=> true, :method => "get", :url => {:action => "show_workflow_list"}, :html => {:id => "subString_form"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :Substring %> <%= f.text_field :subString, :onkeyup => "show_alert()" %>
<%end%>
```

and down below in the same form, I wrote the javascript function for `show_alert()` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function show_alert()
{
    $('#subString_typed_subString').change(function(){$('#subString_form').submit();});
}
</script>
```

Will the above code submit the substring form when I type in a letter in the substring text field?
It does not work for me. Is my jQuery code wrong? My id's are correct in the jQuery code, however I think I am using the wrong function `.change()` for the text field.
Please help

Comment: Are you wanting the form to submit when you keyup? Why not just call `$('#subString_form').submit()` without the change() function

Comment: @Olives thank you, yes, i can use just the $('#subString_form').submit, i'm new to jqeury, so i copy pasted the previous piece of code. I changed it and it is working now

Comment: I've also submitted an answer as the comment as you wanted to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting the form to submit when you keyup? Why not just call $('#subString_form').submit() without the change() function